# How to resize box axes in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I want to resize plot axes in a plot. I am aware that I can use

```
plt.axis('equal')
```

or

```
plt.gca().set_aspect('equal', 'datalim')
```

in order to resize axis in order to have the same unit size on all axis.

[image: datalim]

What I want to do is instead to give the same aspect (square in my case) to the subplot, regardless of unit on x and y axis. In this case the plot must have `xlim = [0, 168]; ylim = [0, 1.01]` .

I tried

```
plt.gca().set_aspect('equal', 'box')
```

but I do not achieve a valid result:

[image: box]

Am I missing something?

Thanks

Comment: You actually obtained what you asked for. Your xspan is much larger then your yspan, so the plot collapses on the `x` axis. I think you do not want the same units. use `plt.gca().set_xlim` to set the axes box that you want.

Comment: Sorry, I do not get it.. I want aspect of 1:1 but using only `set_xlim()` and `set_ylim` I do not change aspect. The image is rectangular (in my opinion) but not a square..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `aspect` applies to the data, you are talking about 1:1 in figure/plot units, eg having a square axes.

You can grab the `xlim` and `ylim` and calculate the aspect yourself:

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2,1)

axs[0].plot(np.random.randn(100).cumsum())
axs[1].plot(np.random.randn(100).cumsum())

aspect = np.diff(axs[1].get_xlim()) / np.diff(axs[1].get_ylim())
axs[1].set_aspect(aspect)
```

[image]

Comment: Just a comment.. is there a particular reason to use `np.diff()` in this case? Anyway, thanks

Comment: No, i just think its convenient since you need the range of the axis. You can also subtract the minimum from the maximum in another way if you please.